# increase variable random with onclick

Tags: javascript, cordova

how do I make the sum of the single key that I pressed??

this is the code:

```
$ (function () {
   var setup = generateOptions (); 
   var tot = 0; 
   $ ("# button1"). val (setup.opzione [0]); 
   $ ("# button2"). val (setup.opzione [1]); 
   $ ("# button3"). val (setup.opzione [2]); 
   $ ("# Button4.") val (setup.opzione [4]); 
   $ ("# Button5.") val (setup.opzione [5]); 
   $ ("# 6 button.") val (setup.opzione [6]); 
   $ ("# pulsante7.") val (setup.opzione [7]); 
   $ ("# pulsante8.") val (setup.opzione [8]); 
   $ ("# pulsante9.") val (setup.opzione [9]); 
   $ ("input.finish.") on ("click", function () {
tot = tot +, and here I do not know that I have to put ... 
     alert (tot); 
   }); 
});
```

virtually every option you see me a number and I wish that when I click the button that value is saved in the variable tot, the numbers that appear are random option of using a random function ...
the are the buttons:

```
<input type="button" class="finish" id="pulsante1">
  <input type="button" class="finish" id="pulsante2">
  <input type="button" class="finish" id="pulsante3">
  <div > <input type="button" class="finish" id="pulsante4">
  <input type="button" class="finish" id="pulsante5">
    <input type="button" class="finish" id="pulsante6">
    <div >   <input type="button" class="finish" id="pulsante7">
      <input type="button" class="finish" id="pulsante8">
      <input type="button" class="finish" id="pulsante9">
    </div>
```

Comment: If he press pulsante6 it will add 6 to tot?

Comment: no, on the 6 button, manifests a random number, between 1 and 10, if I press 6, tot must go on the value that the button has taken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the value of the input with `$(this).val()`, and then convert it to an integer with `parseInt()`. Your click handler should look something like this:

```
$("input.finish").on("click", function() {
    tot += parseInt($(this).val()); 
    alert(tot); 
});
```

Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seiseises/QeL2h/2/), I used random numbers between 1 and 10, but it should work with any other numbers you generate. Hope that helps.

Comment: yes, thank you very much it works, if I can ask one more thing ... I also need the numbers that appear in the buttons change continuously for about 60 seconds .... I tried to put a loop but I do not do it. ..

Comment: You can wrap your code in a function and then use a combination of [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval), [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearInterval) and [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) functions (click links to see the documentation). Check this updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seiseises/QeL2h/3/) with an example, which refreshes the input values every 2 seconds and stops after 15 seconds.

Comment: you're great, I had not thought of that!! 
I take advantage of your willingness to ask you one last thing :) 
I would like to make manifest if only one number type 3000, again at random on the buttons, and this decreased until 3000 I do not press the button, at which point it will manifest itself on another button, and when I press that if the value has reached 3000 was saved in tot?? 
example: 
3000 appears on the button 6 .... 
3000 decreased fairly quickly 
when I press the button, the value that has reached you save in tot 
3000 occurs on another button.

Comment: If I understood you well, that's a bit more complex. You could set another interval for the "3000 button", and use it to decrease its value. The trick here would be choosing the right values, so the time when the "3000 button" reaches 0 matches the time when all the buttons are refreshed. Check the example in [this jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seiseises/DfH8q/1/). I tried to comment the important parts, and notice that I changed a few things from the previous fiddles. Hope it helps.

Comment: you're a big, only to appear only the number 3000 and the other numbers and when I press the key, the 3000 is manifested on another button ...

3000 appears on a button decrements .... just ... I click the button ..... 3000 occurs on another ....

Comment: Sorry, I missed that before, but that's an even more involved case. You can try setting a handler on the button with `specialButton.on('click', someFunction)`, but you'll also have to rearrange some code and think when and where you'll need to stop or start the intervals. I couldn't find a quick way to do it, so try it yourself, experiment with the code, and if you don't find a solution, then post a new question on StackOverflow (this case isn't related to the original question anymore), and someone else will help. Good luck!

Comment: hello, I managed to do what I asked for, the problem is: 

intervalID var = setInterval (function () {
                     specialButton.val (specialButton.val () - 3)​​; 

when I press the button that appears in the 3000 m and the change immediately, but on ul'altro button appears -3 and so on ....